# There exists no Nash equilibrium which is Pareto efficient?

Tags: self-learning, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Prove or Disprove There exists no Nash equilibrium which is Pareto efficient.

My idea is that this sentence is wrong. But I cannot show this. Please share your ideas with me thank you.

Comment: Pareto Optimal is a proper subset of Nash, see, e.g., [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8944817).  It is "easy" to find Nash solutions that aren't Pareto Optimal (as in the Prisoner's Dilemma).